# When do you really need to use Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash

There are a lot of flash effects that can be achieved with jQuery.So when do you really need to use Flash instead of javascript?

Comment: Kinda related but not really: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887071/website-fully-written-or-displayed-in-flash-when-this-is-not-a-good-idea

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply, when you need to do something that jQuery can't do. This includes video/audio, complex animations, cross-browser vector graphics, multi-file uploads, etc. The list goes on.

Of course, you could always write your website in HTML/jQuery and only use Flash for the necessary parts. That way it's a win-win situation, and your application degrades gracefully for those that don't have Flash.

Comment: thanks music freaks, i get what you meant.. A good website should utilise all types of resources available to them.. right?? lol

Comment: Though he does have a great answer, he is only 1 man, *musicfreak* (non plural) ;)

Answer (score 5):

Flash should be considered a 'last resort' in my opinion, and it's one that is shared with many others. Some people use flashblock, so they'll never see it. Users on mobile devices won't see it either.

There are few areas left for flash currently, and HTML5 will likely eliminate one of them.

Comment: I'd agree with you if IE supported HTML5, but it doesn't. Until it supports things like `<audio>`, `<video>`, and `<canvas>`, Flash is the only option for those kinds of things.

Comment: hopefully it's not too far off

Comment: Can't wait for HTML5, and widespread support. IE, damn I hate you.

Answer (score 3):

Only when I have no choice...or asked by my boss

Answer (score 2):

Flash features:

- Compiled byte code versus interpreted
- 2D and 3D geometry libraries
- Animation and audio libraries
- Total control over Fonts/layout/design
- Binary network calls as well as Xml and JSON

I'm not crazy about Flash for brochure or forms sites but it sure is nice for online games.

If your dislike of Flash comes from a dislike of Adobe, check out the [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) programming language. It can target the Flash runtime.

Comment: "# Compiled byte code versus interpreted" - Chrome is still faster than flash. # 2D and 3D geometry libraries Canvas and WebGL?

Comment: @LiraNuna - Good points. Some browsers do offer those Flash features. HTML5 even makes a couple standard. For now, however, they aren't standard and if you want those features for your users you have to decide how to provide them - with a specific browser or a vendor solution (Flash, Java, Silverlight, ActiveX...). Neither approach is ideal. Flash is attractive for its install base. If you throw a rock on the internet, you're likely to hit a Flash browser. Chrome, canvas, and WebGL are perfectly interesting but less frequent (for now).

Answer (score 2):

if you need something which cant be done by JQuery then go for flash. otherwise stick to JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

It is good for times when you want to make screen scraping harder. A major real estate site I worked with used Flash to make it much more difficult for a competitor to scrape agent data.

Sure this could of been done with images but Flash was just easier for us to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Flex, which runs on top of Flash, is a very nice platform for building applications.  In my opinion, it's far better than trying to coerce HTML and JavaScript into being a platform for GUIs.  Also, if you have a graphics designer, they will have a much easier time designing the look and feel with the WYSIWYG tools available in the Adobe tools.

However, for traditional web sites, I'd stick with HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  Don't use Flash if all you need is simple effects.

Comment: Yes, Graphic Designers tend to love doing things in Flash. I love Flash too but sometimes it is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is a frontend tool that should be considered when there are requirements that make a project much easier to develop. I know that there are alot of Flash haters, and I understand the reasons. However, each developer should use the tools available to them that would allow the job to get done effectively and quickly. PHP, HTML and JS have its limits, just like AS3 does as well, but each has something that can help deliver a project.